# Horizontal UIScrollView and multiple thumbnail images in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a horizontal UIScrollView which to hold hundreds of thumbnail images, just like a slide of thumbnails and a UIImageView that will hold the center image of UIScrollView

For example, there will be 6 thumbnails showing in a single screen, each of them are horizontally adjacent to each other.

My problem is that I don't know how to make a horizontal UIScrollView to hold the multiple thumbnails which showing at the same time and then display the center image to the Topview image?

A sample photo is as below. See the bottom part of the screen.
[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4P9I.png)

Comment: You need to look into UICollectionView. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview
sounds like you may have a bit of a learning curve ahead of you. Look up tutorials for "how to create UICollectionView like in the Photos App" - Good Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, here is one:

### The top part

#### Option 1.1

The top image views can be handled by a UIPageViewController wrapping something to the effect of `ImageDetailViewController`

#### Option 1.2

The top is a UICollectionViewController and the large top images are UICollectionViewCells. You can use UICollectionViewFlowLayout with a horizontal scroll direction and pagination true.

### The bottom part

#### Option 2.1

The bottom part should be a UICollectionViewController as you may need to overflow off the screen and it is fast and scrolls horizontally.

#### Option 2.2

The bottom part can be a StackView created with items programmatically and filled in with a spacing you want. Add a UIGestureRecognizer to detect touch down.

### Recommendation

Top: 1.1 - Use a UIPageViewController

Bottom 2.2 - Use a stacked view with a gesture recogniser over the top

Assuming you want them to pan over the bottom, I would say 2.2 is the option, but slightly harder.

So what this looks like is a UIPageViewController, with a floating thumbnail on the bottom to scrub.You can just implement a simple ImageViewer (UIImageView inside a UIScrollView to allow zooming etc).
This will give left/right scroll for **free**.

You will layout the thumbnails on the bottom inside a stack view and it is better to handle one giant gesture recogniser on the bottom so you can keep it continuous without lifting finger. You will just have to get the coordinates or view that is translated inside the touch.

Rather than go into code because there will be a few different classes I will try to give a topographic explanation.

[image: Example architecture]